# Is there an easy way or a plugin to import test plans/test cases from QTest to Azure Devops?

Tags: azure, test-plan, qtest

I just wanted to know if there's a plugin/tool in ADO that imports test cases/Test plans easily from QTest to ADO.

We are looking for different options to move away from QTest. One option we have is to explore ADO to see if that's a best tool for us. The first step is to determine whether we can migrate all of our test case/plan repository in QTest over to ADO. I looked through all the available documentation to import test cases using csv and excel. But they both require a lot of manual work and it seems a cumbersome task as we have more than 10000 test cases in QTest. See below for more explanation. Please suggest if there's a better tool that can map fields between QTest and ADO for a smoother import.